# SASS: select closest

Tags: css, sass, ampersand

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="radio" value="value-0" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <input type="radio" value="value-1" checked="checked" >
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Is there a way in SASS to select `.col`, closest to a checked radio button?

Comment: [Unfortunately, the short answer is "no"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), you cannot select an element based on the presence of any child element.

Answer (score 1):

[Unfortunately no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), you cannot select an element based on the presence of any child element.

A solution for your problem would be to use JavaScript. You can select all your radio buttons, traverse up the DOM tree to find the parent `.col` element (for example, with jQuery's [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function if you're using jQuery, and add a new class to those col elements.

E.g. (**if you're using jQuery**)

```js
$(".col > input[type=radio]").closest(".col").addClass("col-with-radio")
```

...and then you can style the `.col-with-radio` class.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless they are siblings. In the current hierarchy you posted, this is not possible with SASS.